# Exotic uniform algebras

Tags: banach-algebras, ac.commutative-algebra, fa.functional-analysis

The first non-trivial example of a uniform algebra which comes to mind is the disc algebra $A(\mathbb{D})$. In a similar manner one can define its relatives $P(U)$ and $R(U)$, where $U$ is any region on the complex plane and $P$, $R$ stand for the closures, of respectively polynomials and rational functions on $U$.

What if we go beyond the case when spectrum is contained in the complex plane? Rudin proved, that if $K$ is scattered, then there are no non-trivial uniform subalgebras of $C(K)$.

Are there any *classical* or *canonical* examples of uniform algebras with non-metrizable spectra or is the theory of uniform algebras just a daughter of complex analysis?

Forgive me if this question seems to be to vague.

Addendum: A uniform algebra is a closed subalgebra of a commutative C*-algebra $C(K)$ which contains constant functions and separates points in $K$.

Comment: It  might help if you include the definition of a uniform algebra.  Just click the "edit" button to add it.

Comment: Contra MTS, I think that people who might be interested in this question, or able to answer it, know full well what a uniform algebra is. No harm done, in any case.

Comment: Yemon, sure. I mean that all of them are $C(\Omega)$s.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some scattered thoughts: I'm not sure if they really answer what you seem to be driving at.

Complex analysis still gives you examples with nasty maximal ideal spaces, e.g. $H^\infty(\Omega)$. Even when $\Omega$ is the open unit disc, the spectrum is non-metrizable and not at all straightforward to understand (there ought to be some discussion in Gamelin's book).

$L^\infty$ has non-metrizable spectrum, although its structure is in some sense not as mysterious as that of $H^\infty$.

Note that every Banach space $E$ embeds as a closed, complemented subspace of a uniform algebra. Namely, take the canonical map from $E$ into $C(B)$, where $B$ is the closed unit ball of $E^*$ equipped with the weak$*$-topology, and let A be the closed subalgebra generated by the image of $E$. (This is a theorem of Milne; I learned of it from an article of Gamelin and Kislyakov, of which a [preprint version](http://www.mat.univie.ac.at/~esiprpr/esi710.pdf) can be found online.)

Comment: I think you meant 

"every Banach space E embeds as a closed COMPLEMENTED subspace of a uniform algebra."